# (How) can I render the features of a DynamicMapServiceLayer?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, dynamic-layer

I have a webmap that displays the contents of a dynamic map service.  For performance reasons I'm currently using `FeatureLayer`s for the individual sublayers (they are all point layers with relatively few features).

*However*, this makes them show up in the legend as individual items, e.g.:

- **Layer 1**
- **Layer 2**
- **Layer 3**
- **Layer 4**
- **Layer 5**

  when I'd like to group them as they are in the original service:
- **Group 1**

  - Layer 1
  - Layer 2
- **Group 2**

  - Layer 3
- **Group 3**

  - Layer 4
  - Layer 5

Is there a way to load a whole service as with `DynamicMapServiceLayer`, but use `FeatureLayer` rendering for the sublayers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating both (`DynamicMapServiceLayer` and `FeatureLayer`), then adding the DMSL to the Legend but the FLs to the map.  Not pretty, but it works.